# how do i use 2 sepreate moving averages

Tags: pine-script

ma1 is length 11 and offset -1 with the rest of the settings default
ma2 is length 4 and offset -2 with the rest of the settings default
how do I make it so when one crosses the other it enters ?
I don't want to use any other type of "ma" cause they don't let me adjust the offset.
my issue is it seems that pine editor only lets you use 1 "ma"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy together two Moving Average functions, just make sure their variable names do not clash.